# How to format the table with custom objects related to Contacts

Tags: contact, datatable

By default the table for custom related objects only shows name.  You can customize this in salesforce itself, but is there a way to do it through the API?

I'm pretty new to salesforce and the apis.

Comment: table of the custom object- by this do you mean view? the one you get on clicking the tab of  the custom object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy.htm) allows you to deploy the [Layout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_layouts.htm) object, which includes the related lists on a page. You can access this API via [REST](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_updateMetadata.htm) or by [uploading ZIP files](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy.htm). I suggest reading the documentation for more information.

In any case, you basically create a Layout that includes a list of RelatedListItem entries that specify the order on the page, the sort order within the list, and the fields to display. The documentation includes Java examples of how you'd call the API.